# Warning function in R

Tags: r

I have a character list in R. I am executing following query :

```
> a <- c("sepal_length" ,"sepal_width",  "petal_length" ,"petal_width" , "species")
> a
[1] "sepal_length" "sepal_width"  "petal_length" "petal_width" 
[5] "species"     
> warning(a)
Warning message:
sepal_lengthsepal_widthpetal_lengthpetal_widthspecies
```

Notice that above warning message is removing space between character value. I want to use warning function only so is there any way I can get following formatted output.

```
> warning(f(a))
Warning message:
[1] "sepal_length" "sepal_width"  "petal_length" "petal_width" 
[5] "species"
```

Comment: You are writing strange warning messages ...

Comment: haha.. actually whole warning message would be something like.  warning : Column names changed to "sepal_length" "sepal_width"  "petal_length" "petal_width" "species"

Answer (score 3):

Using paste:

```
warning(paste0('"', paste(a, collapse = '" "'), '"'))

Warning message:
"sepal_length" "sepal_width" "petal_length" "petal_width" "species"
```

---

Or as [@akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3732271) suggested, using `dQuote`. This uses *fancy* quotes with no spaces in between:

```
warning(dQuote(a))

Warning message:
“sepal_length”“sepal_width”“petal_length”“petal_width”“species”
```

Comment: It is a fancy quote, but i am not sure whether it matters in the warning message

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `sprintf()`:

```
a <- c("sepal_length" ,"sepal_width",  "petal_length" ,"petal_width" , "species")
warning(sprintf('"%s" ', a))
# Warning message:
# "sepal_length" "sepal_width" "petal_length" "petal_width" "species"
```